# Context of arrow function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

Consider the following example:

```
const f1 = () => this;

function f2() {
    return this;
}

console.log(f1(), f2());
```

When this code is executed in a browser, the result is as follows:

```
> window window
```

But when this code is executed in Node.js, the result is not quite as expected:

```
> {} global
```

Why in Node.js the empty object was taken as the context of an arrow function instead of Global Object (`global` on this platform)?

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs, when you use arrow operator, the this operator won't contain the reference object by nature....thatswhy if we wanted to refer any variables using 'this' , we avoid using arrow operators in function definition.

Therefore in your case this is the reason why it's printing empty object.